# Unable to reproduce results with PyTorch CPU

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, random-seed

I'm training my network on CPU. From PyTorch docs, I read that results may not be reproducible when using GPU because of cudnn. But on CPU, since cudnn is not used, results should be reproducible. I'm setting the seed as follows:

```
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
random.seed(seed)
numpy.random.seed(seed)
torch.manual_seed(seed)
```

Even then I'm getting different results each time I try. Am I missing something?

**Edit**:
Sorry, my bad. There was a problem in code. The above was not called properly. Now, I'm able to get reproducible results.

Comment: Yes, please share your network details. More importantly, though, how do you run the training multiple times? Do you restart the interpreter each time (so every time a new command), or do you do some kind of loop? If you are using a loop, you need to reset the seed every time at the start of the loop.

Comment: @BramVanroy No, I'm restarting the interpreter every time

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can see what may be causing the problem.

Comment: @jodag thanks! But as i stated in the edit to the question, there was some setting wrong in my PyCharm IDE (related to marking folder as source). On fixing that, I'm able to reproduce the results. I'm leaving the question here, in case somebody comes here looking to get reproducible results with PyTorch.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out, I'm voting to close this question since the solution is unrelated to the question.